# How to deal with generic question titles like "why didn't this transaction work..."

Tags: discussion

If we get more questions like [Why isn't msg.sender.send getting called?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/1041/why-does-this-contract-not-send-a-transaction) should we somehow try modifying the title after it's been answered, to be more descriptive, or hint at resolution?

There could be several/many questions titled like: why-does-this-contract-not-send-a-transaction

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The titles on your front page *define* your site, so a title should always, *always* best describe what the question is actually about without having to open the thread. **If it doesn't, you should edit it; always.** It's what helps people with those problems find your site through search.

But someone with a question may not always know the right terminology to accurately describe the problem, so if you can turn a vague title into something more descriptive, go for it. And if you realize a bit of missing context can improve understanding of the question, go ahead and add it. But **I wouldn't change the title from a question into an answer,** if that was what you were implying in your post.

E.g.

- *Can you help with this problem?* ← **This is a non-title**
- *What's wrong with my ice cream?* ← **Still very poor**
- *Why does my ice cream melt after I take it out of the freezer?* ← ***PERFECT!***

however…

- *How to keep ice cream solid by storing it in the freezer* ← **Don't turn a title into a hint/answer**

Comment: Thanks, a little hard to find a better title for the specified question and we'll try to do it for others.