# How to handle transaction tracing requests?

Tags: discussion

There are a fair number of questions like [this one](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/43737/eth-never-delivered-wallet-to-wallet) where the poster wonder about what happened as a result of a fairly typical transaction. They're somewhat related to [How to deal with generic question titles like "why didn't this transaction work..."](https://ethereum.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/131/how-to-deal-with-generic-question-titles-like-why-didnt-this-transaction-work), but not really in my mind. While they are distinct questions (they are transaction-specific questions), so they're not closable as duplicates (maybe?), I feel like this is bordering on the "third-party support" line. That, and I think the solution is often the same. Go to a blockchain explorer, look at the transaction, and say something like

- your transaction went through.
- gas limit is too low, so transaction failed.
- your transaction hasn't been confirmed, yet or wasn't posted.
- your transaction isn't what you thought it was (e.g., wrong recipient).

I added the tag `transaction-tracing` to the post above and gave an answer about what happened in that particular case (the transaction went through -- probably had the wrong recipient), but that's about as much as I knew what to do.

Comment: Your steps look good. One possibility is putting some of this question into an answer, accepting the answer, and when these requests are made in SE, flag them and link to here https://ethereum.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/578/how-to-handle-transaction-tracing-requests as you're reason for closing...

Comment: I would recommend making a generic wiki question and answer "How to troubleshoot a failed transaction" and close as duplicates

Comment: Another one is that if the transactions are related to specific service (exchange) then just close them as a third party customer support, as you wrote